# num_row manipulation in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, function

i have this function that brings me back a value by query a table in the database!

the code:

```
function recycle_check($recycle_id){

     $query = "SELECT recycle_id FROM notes WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' and recycle_id ='$recycle_id'";
           if(mysql_num_rows($query)== 0)
                return 0;
            else
                return 1;
}
```

but its giving me an error saying:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource
```

i just want the function to either give me a zero or a number 1!

```
0 for exists and 1 for deosnt exist!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to run `mysql_query` before calling to `mysql_num_rows`

[like](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

what you need to pass to the function is:

> The result resource that is being
>   evaluated. This result comes from a
>   call to mysql_query().